# Tried to do a git pull and there were merge conflicts. Tried git mergetool but no tool started

Tags: git, git-svn

I tried to do a git pull origin develop and it tried merging but there were some conflicts.
I tried git mergetool but it doesn't start up a tool. This is first time I've tried to merge
How do I merge my changes?

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .classpath
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
....Tool (develop|MERGING)
$ git mergetool
merge tool candidates: tortoisemerge emerge vimdiff
No known merge resolution program available.
```

Comment: can you show your git config --list, without your personnal data ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the error message:

```
No known merge resolution program available.
```

`git` can not find a merge tool it knows how to use.  So either, you don't have a usable merge tool installed or you do but it's not on the path when `git` is run.

Answer (score 0):

Probable reason is you have not yet configured your merging tool.
You can determine this in your ~/.gitconfig the tools as the following screenshot.

[image: sample git config]

In your case however, you could provide paths from your tortoisemerge, emerge or vimdiff.